# problems with counting vowels, checking starts with or ends with a vowel in words

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

Consider the below code to count the occurrence of letter 'a' in each of the words:

```
data <- data.frame(number=1:4, string=c("this.is.a.great.word", "Education", "Earth.Is.Round", "Pinky), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(stringr)

data$Count_of_a <- str_count(data$string, "a")

data
```

Which will result into something like this:

```
  number               string Count_of_a
1      1 this.is.a.great.word          2
2      2            Education          1
3      3       Earth.Is.Round          1
4      4       Pinky                   0
```

I was trying to do couple of more things:

1. compute the total of vowels in each word
2. total no. of letters in each word
3. whether a word starts with a vowel, then 1 else 0
4. whether a word ends with a vowel, then 1 else 0

Problem is if I use nchar(data$string), it also counts dots '.'
also i could not find much help on the above 4 requirements.

final data I wanted to look like this:

```
number    string                 starts_with_vowel   ends_with_vowel   TotalLtrs
1         this.is.a.great.word          0                 0             16
2         Education                     1                 0             9
3         Earth.Is.Round                1                 0             12
4         Pinky                         0                 1             5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a combination of regex expressions

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(
    nvowels = str_count(tolower(string), "[aeoiu]"),
    total_letters = str_count(tolower(string), "\\w"),
    starts_with_vowel = grepl("^[aeiou]", tolower(string)),
    ends_with_vowel = grepl("[aeiou]$", tolower(string))
  )


# number               string nvowels total_letters starts_with_vowel ends_with_vowel
# 1      1 this.is.a.great.word       6            16             FALSE           FALSE
# 2      2            Education       5             9              TRUE           FALSE
# 3      3       Earth.Is.Round       5            12              TRUE           FALSE
# 4      4                Pinky       1             5             FALSE           FALSE
```

If you consider `y` a vowel, add it like so

```
nvowels = str_count(tolower(string), "[aeoiuy]")
starts_with_vowel = grepl("^[aeiouy]", tolower(string))
ends_with_vowel = grepl("[aeiouy]$", tolower(string))
```

Comment: Actually you are right. whenever we have 'y' in the end of a word, usually we consider it as a vowel e.g. cry, dry, city etc.

Comment: but there is an issues, if we consider `y` as `vowel` when it is at the end place of the word, then the `count should also be increased by 1`, so your code did not consider it.

Comment: I wasn't clear about how to edit all cases - simply add `y` to all `[...]` regex expressions - the `[aeiou]` simply indicates which characters to count.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
str_count(df$string, "a|e|i|o|u|A|E|I|O|U")
[1] 6 5 5 1

str_count(df$string, paste0(c(letters,LETTERS), collapse = "|"))
[1] 16  9 12  5

ifelse(substr(df$string, 1, 1) %in% c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"), 1, 0)
[1] 0 1 1 0

ifelse(substr(df$string, nchar(df$string), nchar(df$string)) %in% c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"), 1, 0)
[1] 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks Len for this effort and i am obliged. let me review it.